# The same non static object used by NUnit when tests running in parallel

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, nunit-3.0

I recently switched from MsTest to Unit3 and I noticed that when my tests are running in parallel the same non-static property is shared between all tests.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using NUnit.Framework;
[assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.All)]
namespace Nunit3netcore
{
    public class User
    {

    }
    public class Tests
    {
        public User User { get; set; }

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            User = new User();
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            TestContext.WriteLine(User.GetHashCode());
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test2()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            TestContext.WriteLine(User.GetHashCode());

        }

        [Test]
        public void Test5()
        {

            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            TestContext.WriteLine(User.GetHashCode());
        }
    }
}
```

For each test output, I see that the hash code is the same.When I comment out assembly:Parralilzable attribute and my code is running in non-paralell the hash code is different for each test. In MsTest I was generated a new object with new hash code withing [TestInitialize] method. How can I achieve that using Nunit.
Packages I use:
Nunit 3.12.0
Nunit3TestAdapter 3.16.1
Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk (16.5.0)

Answer (score 0):

I already answered this on GitHub, but I'll repeat it here so that others have the answer as well. [Suggestion: Pick a place to ask first, ask and then wait at least a few hours to see if you get an answer.]

Since you didn't show any override of `GetHashCode()`, I'll assume that the underlying `System.Object.GetHashCode()` is being used here. HashCodes are used by .NET as a preliminary test of equality and the way they work is that unequal codes guarantee **inequality**, while equal codes indicate that the two instances **may be equal**.  Further value checks are usually needed.

The implementation of hash codes has changed with various versions of .NET. In this case, my guess is that it's getting some info for the hash from the executing thread itself. But, in any case (1) it isn't NUnit generating the hash code and (2) it's not correct to assume that every hash code is unique.

In cases where you're concerned about the specifics of hash code generation for a particular Type, then you should be overriding `GetHashCode()`. In that case, you should also override `Equals()`, since the two work together.

It's not really related to the question, but I want to suggest that use of

```
[assembly:Parallelizable(ParallelScope.All)]
```

isn't really a great practice. That line of code tells NUnit "Hey, all my tests in this assembly are capable of running in parallel, and any I add in the future will be too." If you are ready to make that promise, then you may be a better programmer than me. :-)

It's a common misconception to think that NUnit "does something" to make it possible for tests to run in parallel. That's not so. It just accepts your promise that they will work and runs them that way.